# how to define reference on migration with an existing column rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to define the foreign key for a model migration using an existing column,I want to set codproducto as foreign key of a table called invmtoproducto, here is my new model migration:

```
class CreateDetalleinveacs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :detalleinveacs do |t|
      t.integer :correlativo
      t.integer :cantidad
      t.decimal :valor, precision: 20, scale: 10
      t.decimal :costo, precision: 30, scale: 20
      t.string :nis
      t.datetime :feacceso
      t.integer :codproducto
      t.integer :idinveac
    end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
add_foreign_key :detalleinveacs, :invmtoproducto, column: :codproducto
```

Your migration would then look like this:

```
class CreateDetalleinveacs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :detalleinveacs do |t|
      t.integer :correlativo
      t.integer :cantidad
      t.decimal :valor, precision: 20, scale: 10
      t.decimal :costo, precision: 30, scale: 20
      t.string :nis
      t.datetime :feacceso
      t.integer :codproducto
      t.integer :idinveac
    end

    # Add a foreign key constraint 
    # from the 'detalleinveacs' table 
    # to the 'invmtoproducto' table 
    # where the foreign key column 'codproducto' of the 'detalleinveacs' table 
    # references the 'id' column of the 'invmtoproducto' table.
    add_foreign_key :detalleinveacs, :invmtoproducto, column: :codproducto
  end
end
```

In case the foreign key references a column different than `id` on the `invmtoproducto` table, it is possible to override that default:

```
add_foreign_key :detalleinveacs, 
                :invmtoproducto, 
                column: :codproducto,
                primary_key: :some_column_other_than_id
```

Please see the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) for further details

Comment: Im not sure of where should I add this, I try outside the create table block but it doesnt work, is it an especific command or it should be inside the migration?

Comment: @AlexQuezada I have elaborated on the possibilities. In particular, I have added the option to specifiy a primary_key other than `id` as your tables might not follow the default naming conventions. If this does not suffice, please state the error so I can offer some specific advice.

Comment: thank you, it worked! I had an error because on the invmtoproducto table the constraint wasnt defined, but once I fixed that it worked like a charm!